# Why does the index show -1?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

iam trying to get the index from the sqlite database, i got all the data but only one value shows -1 and the app crash

```
int weightColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT);
Log.v("the weight index","-->"+weightColumnIndex);
int weight = cursor.getInt(weightColumnIndex);
```

this is the result of log message

V/the weight index: -->-1

and this is the error in the logcat

> 03-29 15:24:10.456 21309-21309/com.example.android.pets
>   E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow
>   which has 1 rows, 5 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this line:

```
int weightColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT);
```

returns `-1` then the cause might be one of the following:

- In your query you did not select the column `PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT` so it does not exist in the results.
- Your table does not contain a column named `PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT`!
   
  Maybe you made changes in your table's schema after the first time you ran the app like adding or renaming this column in the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and you think that this change would be immediately reflected to the table, but this is not how it works. 
  The `onCreate()` method is not called every time you run the app.
  It is called only when the database does not already exist (or you may call it directly say from the `onUpgrade()` method when you change the version of the database). 
  So uninstall the app from the device where you test it, so the database is deleted and rerun. 
  This way the database will be recreated and the `onCreate()` method will be executed to create the table(s) with the most recent schema as it is defined in the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.

Comment: Thank you so much you are comment it solved the issue ,
i forget to add the column in the query